# I want to convert date format mm/dd/yyyy into dd/mm/yyyy in jquery

Tags: jquery, date, jquerydatetimepicker

i have used datepicker function on my text field but when i select any date
it shows date mm/dd/yyyy format but i want dd/mm/yyyy format. my code is like this

```
<div class="col-sm-4 input-append date form_datetime" data-provide="datepicker">
  <p align="left">Date Of Birth (DD/MM/YYYY):</p>
    <input type="text" size="16" name="dob" pattern="" id="dob" placeholder="Date Of Birth (DD/MM/YYYY)" class="form-control "/>
      </div>


$(function () {

    $("#dob").datepicker({

    });
```

Comment: use dateFormat like `dateFormat: 'dd m yy',`

Comment: thank you sir.. works for me.

Comment: @glad to help i posted an answer so we can close the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#dob").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd / mm / yy',
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" size="16" name="dob" pattern="" id="dob" placeholder="Date Of Birth (DD/MM/YYYY)" class="form-control " />
```

use `dateFormat`